# Is there an HTML5 shiv for video, that automatically loads a flash player when HTML5 is not available, but otherwise uses native HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video

I know there are great HTML5 wrapper projects like these:

http://www.mediaelementjs.com/

http://videojs.com/

https://afterglowplayer.com/

But I would like to **use the native HTML5 player**, and only when HTML5 is not available, then fallback to a flash player. It seems most of these projects try to become a unified video player, which I do not want.

is there any HTML5 video "shiv" out there that loads a flash player only when HTML5 is not available? Does it work with the native javascript bindings like `timeupdate`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Video.js does do that. It uses HTML5 video and only loads flash when there isn't support for HTML5 video.

Comment: [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/video-for-everybody-html5-video-with-flash-fallback/) is a technique.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

- **OGG:** This will make Firefox happy. You can use VLC (File -> Streaming/Export
  Wizard) to convert your video to this format easily.
- **MP4:** Many screencasting tools automatically export to Mp4; so you can use that file for Safari and Chrome.
- **FLV/.SWF:** Not all browsers support HTML 5 video, of course. To compensate, make sure that you add a fallback Flash version as well.

  ```
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
      <title>Video</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <video controls width="500">
      <!-- if Firefox -->
      <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
      <!-- if Safari/Chrome-->
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <!-- If the browser doesn't understand the <video> element, then reference a Flash file. You could also write something like "Use a Better Browser!" if you're feeling nasty. (Better to use a Flash file though.) -->
      <embed src="http://blip.tv/play/gcMVgcmBAgA%2Em4v" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1024" height="798" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
  </video>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: I know the general way to fallback to flash. It's the `swf` part that I am interested in. I am wondering if someone developed a generic `.swf` that accepts html5 api calls and acts like an html5 player when html5 is not available. **My assumption is, this is not a thing.**